# Error in installing node-sass package of version 4.12.0

Tags: node-sass

I have a template of react website, all the packages are installed successfully except node-sass. This package gives the following error during installation "npm ERR! Cannot read properties of null (reading 'children')

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\Ashir\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-08-31T12_57_40_451Z-debug-0.log"

I write command npm i node-sass

Error
"npm ERR! Cannot read properties of null (reading 'children')

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\Ashir\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-08-31T12_57_40_451Z-debug-0.log"